# Website not recognising stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress

I have what seems a very basic problem - my Wordpress site doesn't seem to be recognising the stylesheet. I've developed my own - first - WP theme, and it works fine on my local system. I've uploaded it to a free host to test it live, but it doesn't look like the stylesheet is being recognised.
The website is http://k1demo.byethost6.com , and in style.css I have imported the style sheet from my css folder which has been compiled from a LESS file.
Here is the code in my style.css file:

```
@import url("/css/styles.css");
```

And in my header.php the stylesheet is called as such from the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: relation to php/wordpress is? as you tagged with

Comment: btw, this is wrong `href="type="text/css"` remove the `href="` and is a typo/off-topic by Stack's standards. Also make sure your paths are correct. You're using `url("/css/styles.css")` and `href="style.css"` in the other. Are both in the same folder or not?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was something in the php file... have removed php for now, and fixed my glaring code error, thanks for pointing it out. Still not working though. No style.css is in the root, styles is in the css folder.

Comment: well this `href="type="text/css"` as I stated is incorrect. It should just read as `type="text/css"` if that's your real code.

Comment: Yes that has been changed, but still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: see miro's answer. I didn't load your entire site, but (s)he obviously did.

Comment: if it's a PHP issue and path related, then error reporting would have told you about it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

What a mess. Currently in your code you are loading:

http://k1demo.byethost6.com/style.css

And it doesn't exist. You need to load:

http://k1demo.byethost6.com/wp-content/themes/K1/style.css

From then `@import url("/css/styles.css");` looks at the [root]/css/ which leads to:

http://k1demo.byethost6.com/css/styles.css

It also doesn't exist.

Comment: That file `@import url("/css/styles.css");` is still not there. Where is your custom css?

Comment: I've updated the path to "http://k1demo.byethost6.com/wp-content/themes/K1/css/styles.css" - which is where the file is.

Comment: The file is not there. Go to that link and you'll get 404

Comment: I kept thinking it was.... and it was... but I've named the folder CSS. I simply didn't realise that the path was case sensitive, which again I'm sure is a very basic thing to overlook. Thanks miro and everyone, I accept the downvotes for this...

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Windows doesn't care about the case but linux is sensitive. Glad it worked.  Also you don't need the entire url in the import. Use just `CSS/styles.css`. P.S. Not my down votes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your syntax is a little messed up...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: yeah  I said that; twice.

Comment: looks like op has bigger fish to fry anyway

Comment: the problem seems to go deeper than this. Edit: Now the OP just made the correction.

Comment: Yes looks like I have plenty more fish to fry, too many basic problems - made the above changes, still not working.Thanks for pointing these things out though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are trying to access the root of your theme folder, while in reality you are hitting the root of your website.

If you want to enqueue the stylesheet directly in the header.php do the following in your `href=""` to target any file in your theme folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
```

But I strongly recommend you to let WordPress handle the enqueueing of your scripts and stylesheets in your functions.php.

```
function enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'THEMENAME_style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '0.0.1' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );
```

**See the documentation of wp_enqueue_style:**
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

**Note:**
If you want your theme to support child themes, you can use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` instead. This function will look in the child theme folder first, if it doesn't find the file, it will look in the parent theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

The file path needed to be case sensitive, after changing that the css is now working. Very basic mistake...